# Rewrite Url is not working in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, cakephp-2.0

I want to change the URL Structure of my site for https://www.compareking.no/post-detail.php?post-id=1 to https://www.compareking.no/postdetail/post-id/1. But it is not working for SSl site

My code is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  # Turn mod_rewrite on
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^/postdetail/([0-9]+)$ /post-detail.php?post-id=$1
```

Comment: Your rewrite rule seems to work with this url `https://www.compareking.no/postdetail/1` (remove post-id) OR try this `RewriteRule ^/postdetail/post-id/([0-9]+)$ /post-detail.php?post-id=$1`

Comment: @ASR I tried your way. But not work. If you have another solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**No `/` at beginning of url in `.htaccess`**

You are nearly there. The `/` at the beginning of your url will never match (though it would in `httpd.comf`). Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule postdetail/([0-9]+)/?$ post-detail.php?post-id=$1 [B,QSA,L]
```

Comment: I tried it but not working. And .htaccess file is working. I have remove .php from the url and that works.